# How to change the font size of line numbers in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I want to increase the font size of the line numbers in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate(2019.3.1) independently from changing the font of the code itself but I can't find the way of doing so.

[image]

I shook the whole Internet and didn't find anything up to date either. Actions search didn't help as well.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font size of line numbers automatically changes along with the font size of code in the editor. It uses the same font setting(font, font size, etc).
You can try to adjust font.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-editor-font.html

And as **Improbable** mentioned, there is a feature request for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92443

Comment: This was confirmed. You can add this [official request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92443) as a formal proof of your words and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Addition: The formal proof that the font size of line numbers can't be changed independently from the font of the code in the editor itself.